# VB.NET Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Function Exists(path As String) As Boolean'

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I cannot seem to figure this out, why am I getting this error `(Error 1 Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Function Exists(path As String) As Boolean')`?

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim CopyFile As String
    Dim CopyTo As String

    CopyFile = src1.Text
    CopyTo = dest1.Text

    If System.IO.File.Exists(CopyFile) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Exists(src1.Text, dest1.Text)
        MsgBox("Copied!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: be sure to accept answers by clicking the check next to the one which worked.  if someone took the time to help, take the time to mark them off   http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to copy the file. So instead of

```
System.IO.File.Exists(src1.Text, dest1.Text)
```

you need

```
System.IO.File.Copy(src1.Text, dest1.Text)
```

Comment: Thanks but I was expecting it to move the file into the directory and not have to already have a file in there with the same name. Is it possible to insert a file without it already existing in the folder?

Comment: Your code doesn't require the file to be in the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload as `File.Exists(string,string)` for method see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As per my understanding, if you want to copy file Use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
System.IO.File.Copy(src1.Text, dest1.Text)
```